# How do I create and populate a Dictionary<string,Object> using Unity's xml configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

How do I create and populate a Dictionary using Unity's xml configuration?

I need to create a Dictionary and populate the objects using dependency references in unity.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I gave up and used spring.net :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

    <alias alias="MyStuffObject" type="MyStuffObject, MyStuff"/>
    <!-- dictionary stuff -->
    <alias alias="IDictionaryOfStuff" type="System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[MyStuffObject, MyStuff]], mscorlib"/>
    <alias alias="DictionaryOfStuff" type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[MyStuffObject, MyStuff]], mscorlib"/>

    <!-- Containers -->
    <container name="Stuff">

        <register type="IDictionaryOfStuff" mapTo="DictionaryOfStuff" name="dictionaryOfStuff">
            <constructor />
            <method name="Add">
                <param name="key" type="System.String" value="Cool_Key"/>
                <param name="value" type="IClinicalDocumentParser" dependencyName="coolStuffObject"/>
            </method>
        </register>

        <register type="MyStuffObject" mapTo="MyStuffObject" name="coolStuffObject" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

Comment: I am trying to implement a similar solution but I am having a hard time following your configuration without any code that uses it. Can you please help me out? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129606/unity-ioc-dynamic-resolution?noredirect=1#comment73338974_43129606) is my posted question. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create some sort of parsing system.

You can use the XML system in .Net to parse the XML code and then add it to the dictionary by doing dictionary.Add();

Comment: I got it to work using straight unity, but dictionary.Add() was the key.