# Unity IoC dynamic resolution

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to resolve some dependencies which will only be known at runtime. I am using configuration file to configure Unity (**not programmatically**).

Here is some code to show what I want to achieve.

**Classes:**

```
internal class WorkflowFactory : IWorkflowFactory
{
    public IItemWorkflow GetWorkflow(string discriminator)
    {
        // return an implementation of IItemWorkflow as specified in config file
        return null;
    }
}

public interface IWorkflowFactory
{
    IItemWorkflow GetWorkflow(string discriminator);
}

public interface IItemWorkflow
{
    void Handle(int id);

    // More methods
}
```

**Usage:**

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWorkflowFactory factory = new WorkflowFactory();

        // I am using args to show I do not know the string until runtime
        var wf1 = factory.GetWorkflow(args[0]); 
        var wf2 = factory.GetWorkflow(args[1]);
    }
}
```

If you know a better way, I am totally open and invite suggestions.

Comment: Will named registration (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=pandp.20).aspx#config_registerelement) work for your case?

Comment: I read that before posting but how would I do that? What would I put in my `GetWorkflow` method?

Comment: `container.Resolve<IItemWorkflow>(discriminator)` (assuming all choices are registered in config file with corresponding "name" attribute).

Comment: Apart from named instances, another approach is to go with injection factory (http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2011/06/12/unity-and-injection-with-factories.aspx)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov unfortunately I will need to get the container to the factory and that is not an option I have.

Comment: @Saravanan That will not work. I read that already. My issues is that the only thing I have is the string `discriminator` and I am using config files.

Comment: @CodingYoshi you can't get to the container... like at all? You can't even use service locator? Can you explain what you can do than? Without access to container somewhere there is no way to resolve objects through it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If I am able to construct a dictionary through my unity configuration, I can then use the dictionary in my factory. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597492/how-do-i-create-and-populate-a-dictionarystring-object-using-unitys-xml-confi). I am trying to figure that out so if you have an answer similar to that, it will work. Then I will not need the container.

Comment: I'm still confused how you expect Unity to magically provide you instances... You sample code shows no Unity integration (should be at least something like `IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
    .LoadConfiguration();` in main (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507504(v=pandp.30).aspx)... And then you can just resolve that dictionary and pass it to your factory (also you could just resolve factory itself if it has the dictionary as argument). Showing some more realistic sample would help to understand what is blocking you.

Comment: I have the `LoadConfiguration` code in the composition root and i did not include that in my sample since I mentioned I will load everything using config configuration. If that helps, I can include it tomorrow. If i can resolve a dictionary and pass it in to my factory, that would be awesome. But i had a hard time doing a dictionary population within the config file.